# Adding Zoom behavior to custom map points

Tags: javascript, d3.js

As an exercise to learn D3, I used a dataset from a previous project on the locations and names of airports all over the world. I'm loading this into my webpage using D3.csv and plotting the points on a map using topojson.

At this point in my exercise, I'm trying to add a feature to let users zoom in & out on the world map. As you can imagine, there are a lot of airports and the map gets crowded since I haven't added any filter logic yet.

Darndest thing is, I can get the Zoom behavior to work on countries, but I'm unsure how to get it to work on the circles I've drawn. If I zoom in on my map using the scroll-wheel, the map zooms in, but the circles stay in place.

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .feature {
        fill: none;
        stroke: grey;
        stroke-width: 1px;
        stroke-linejoin: round;
    }
    .mesh {
        fill: none;
        stroke: lightgrey;
        stroke-width: 2px;
        stroke-linejoin: round;
    }
    h1 {
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    svg {
  background: #eee;
}

.sphere {
  fill: #fff;
}

.land {
  fill: #000;
}

.boundary {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;
}

.overlay {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

circle{
  fill: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;  
}

.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Lots of airports across the world</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
var width = 950,
    height = 550;
    scale0 = (width - 1) / 2 / Math.PI;

var projection = d3.geo.mercator();

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    .scale(scale0)
    .scaleExtent([scale0, 8 * scale0])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g");

var g = svg.append("g");

var circle = svg.append("circle");

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "overlay")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg
    .call(zoom)
    .call(zoom.event);

var tip = d3.tip()
    .attr("class", "d3-tip")
    .offset([-10, 0])
    .html(function(d) {
        return "Name" + ": " + d[2] + "<br>" + "Location" + ": " + d[3];
    });

svg.call(tip);

d3.json("world-110m.v1.json", function(error, world) {
  if (error) throw error;

  g.append("g")
      .attr("d", path)
      .on("click", clicked)
      .on("zoom", zoomed);

  g.append("path")
      .datum({type: "Sphere"})
      .attr("class", "sphere")
      .attr("d", path);

  g.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.merge(world, world.objects.countries.geometries))
      .attr("class", "land")
      .attr("d", path);

  g.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(world, world.objects.countries, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("class", "boundary")
      .attr("d", path)
      .on("click", clicked);

    d3.csv("output.csv",
        function(data) {return {name: data.Airport_name, location: data.Location_served, 
            long : +data.Longitude, lat : +data.Latitude}},
        function(data) {
        var new_array = data.map(function (d) {return [d.long, d.lat, d.name, d.location]});
        console.log("new", new_array)

        svg.selectAll("circle")
            .data(new_array)
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("cx", function (d) { return projection(d)[0]; })
            .attr("cy", function (d) { return projection(d)[1]; })
            .attr("r", "2px")
            .on("mouseover", tip.show)
            .on("mouseout", tip.hide);
        });

    }) //closes the json, do not move.

// begin click-zoom listeners
function clicked(d) {
    console.log("d:",d)
  var centroid = path.centroid(d),
      translate = projection.translate();

  projection.translate([
    translate[0] - centroid[0] + width / 2,
    translate[1] - centroid[1] + height / 2
  ]);

  zoom.translate(projection.translate());

  g.selectAll("path").transition()
      .duration(700)
      .attr("d", path);
}

function zoomed() {
  projection.translate(d3.event.translate).scale(d3.event.scale);
  g.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);
}
</script>    
</body>
```

So what starts looking like this [image: Looking like this]

ends looking like this upon zooming in [image: this upon zoom]

I'd like the circles to move as well as the countries.

CSV sample:

```
Airport_name,DST,IATA,ICAO,Location_served,Time,Latitude,Longitude
Anaa Airport,,AAA,NTGA,"Anaa, Tuamotus, French Polynesia",UTC?10:00,-16.9419074,-144.8646172
Arrabury Airport,,AAB,YARY,"Arrabury, Queensland, Australia",UTC+10:00,-26.7606354,141.0269959
El Arish International Airport,,AAC,HEAR,"El Arish, Egypt",UTC+02:00,31.1272509,33.8045859
Adado Airport,,AAD,,"Adado (Cadaado), Galguduud, Somolia",UTC+03:00,9.56045635,31.65343724
Rabah Bitat Airport (Les Salines Airport),,AAE,DABB,"Annaba, Algeria",UTC+01:00,36.8970249,7.7460806
Apalachicola Regional Airport,Mar-Nov,AAF,KAAF,"Apalachicola, Florida, United States",UTC?05:00,29.7258675,-84.9832278
Arapoti Airport,Oct-Feb,AAG,SSYA,"Arapoti, Paraná, Brazil",UTC?03:00,-24.1458941,-49.8228117
Merzbrück Airport,Mar-Oct,AAH,EDKA,"Aachen, North Rhine-Westphalia, Germany",UTC+01:00,50.776351,6.083862
Arraias Airport,,AAI,SWRA,"Arraias, Tocantins, Brazil",UTC?03:00,-12.9287788,-46.9437231
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your zoom function does two things, it modifies the projection and updates the paths using the modified projection:

```
function zoomed() {
  projection.translate(d3.event.translate).scale(d3.event.scale); // modify the projection
  g.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);   // update the paths
}
```

Ok, so in addition to modifying the paths on each zoom using the bound datum, we need to modify the circles:

```
function zoomed() {
  projection.translate(d3.event.translate).scale(d3.event.scale); // modify the projection
  g.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);   // update the paths

  // update the circles/points:
  svg.selectAll("circle")
    .attr("cx", function (d) { return projection(d)[0]; })
    .attr("cy", function (d) { return projection(d)[1]; })
  });
}
```

---

However this doesn't quite work, we need to see how you append the circles:

```
    svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(new_array)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function (d) { return projection(d)[0]; })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return projection(d)[1]; })
```

This is great if there is no circle already on the svg - but there is, you appended one here:

```
var circle = svg.append("circle");
```

Which means that the first airport in the array won't be added as there is already a circle in the svg for that item in the data array. A null selection (d3.selectAll(null)) will ensure that an item is entered for every item in the data array.

Most importantly here, is that the first circle doesn't have a bound datum until after the data has loaded. This will cause some issues when calling the zoom, there is no bound data to use to rescale the circle and you'll get an error. Instead, you could append the airports with a class and select these during zoom events.

In my example [here](http://%20http://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/9d1dedca246a3fc51cbef1adaaafa3f3) I've used a null selection to enter the airports, and given them a class so I can easily select the circles that I want to re position based on an updated projection. (For demonstration, I also simplified the world map and increased the point radius).

This looks like:

```
function zoomed() {
  projection.translate(d3.event.translate).scale(d3.event.scale);
  g.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);

 svg.selectAll(".airport")
   .attr("cx", function (d) { return projection(d)[0]; })
   .attr("cy", function (d) { return projection(d)[1]; }) 
}
```

With the enter being:

```
    svg.selectAll()   // selectAll() is equivilant to selectAll(null)
        .data(new_array)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class","airport")
        .attr("cx", function (d) { return projection(d)[0]; })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return projection(d)[1]; })
        .attr("r", "6px")
        .on("mouseover", tip.show)
        .on("mouseout", tip.hide);
    });
```

Comment: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" 

How does the data used to generate my points get read outside of the d3.csv function?

Comment: Ah I didn't see you were appending an extra circle: `svg.append("circle");` this doesn't have a bound datum. The zoom is using the data bound to the points (same as it is for the paths when it redraws them), I'll edit. Though if you can provide a sample of your data I can make a proper demonstration.

Comment: Sample added to the main question

Comment: Thanks, I hope I'm clear in the updated answer (with [example](http://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/9d1dedca246a3fc51cbef1adaaafa3f3)) - it's too early or something to speak clearly for me.

Comment: That is quite a demonstration! Thanks, I'll do some more reading on appending elements and also adding & manipulating class attributes.